# JQuery Array To Re-arranged JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to covert this javascript Array

```
    [
      "Data",
          [
                "API",
                "Apiales",
                "Apiaceae",
                "Apia",
          ]
      ]
```

to this rearranged json Format

```
   

    [
     {"name":"API","id":"1"},
     {"name":"Apiales","id":"1"},
     {"name":"Apiaceae","id":"1"},
     {"name":"Apia","id":"1"}
    ]
```

Thanks

update:
i have tried this

```
var aNewData =[];
             for(i in aData[1]){
             var item={};
             item.name = aData[1][i];
             item.id = "1";
             aNewData[i]=item;
            }
```

Comment: And those id's are coming out of thin air? Or are they just counting up starting from 20?

Comment: id's were just there as an example to get an idea about how to relate to second key:pair value  if needed,Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do the ids come from? Test following script, your array is in `aData` and the result will be in `aNewData`:

```
var aNewData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < aData[1].length; i++) {
    aNewData.push({
        "name": aData[1][i],
        "id": 20 + i
    });
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tM3Sf/).

Comment: Thanks scessor,is it Performance wise better than my updated solution?

Comment: You're welcome. There should be no performance difference between our solutions.

Comment: @JaideepSingh Using `for...in` to iterate on an array is not a good practice. Use a simple `for` as *scessor* did. [Read more about the reasons for not using `for...in` on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You might easily transform those data via folding:

```
var sourceData  = ["API","Apiales","Apiaceae","Apia"];
var transformed = sourceData.reduce(function(result, name, index) {
  return result.concat({
    name: name,
    id: 20 + index
  });
}, []);
```

This will give you essentially the same, as the for loop of scessor, but in a more data-centric way.

Think of it like this:

1. You hold your source data (the array with all those "api*" strings)
2. You create a fresh resulting array `[]` (passed as 2nd argument to the `reduce`), which should be returned as your next result.
3. Pass an unnamed function to `reduce` that will be called with 3 arguments, each time it is called, namely `result`, which is you recently created array, `name` the value of each of those "api*" strings, and `index`, which is the index of those strings within the original array.
4. You look at each of those "api*" strings consecutively and put a new object containing your desired data into it. As `result.concat` will return the whole array, you just add those
5. The `result` array containing all your data will be returned.

But just in case you wanted to be backward compatible with older browsers, I'd recommend using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for that.

Comment: Thanks,Learned Many Things From Your Answer

Comment: That's what I've hoped. Glad you could make use of it ;)